# View cURL request headers complete with POST data

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

How can I view the full request headers, ***including post data***, using libcurl in php?

I am trying to simulate the post of a page, which when done from a browser and viewed in Live HTTP Headers looks like this:

```
https://###.com
POST /###/### HTTP/1.1
Host: ###.###.com
...snipped normal looking headers...
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------28001808731060
Content-Length: 697
-----------------------------28001808731060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_data"; filename="stats.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
id,stats_id,scope_id,stat_begin,stat_end,value
61281,1,4,2011-01-01 00:00:00,2011-12-31 23:59:59,0
-----------------------------28001808731060
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="-save"
Submit
-----------------------------28001808731060--
```

So we nicely see the file I'm uploading, it's content, everything's there. But all my attempts at getting data out of cURL when I try to make the same post from php (using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, or `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT`) show request headers that lack the post data, like so:

```
POST /###/### HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Host: ###.###.com
...snipped normal-looking headers...
Content-Length: 697
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------e90de36c15f5
```

Based on the Content-Length here, it appears things are going well, but it would really help my debugging efforts to be able to see the complete request. I am also irked that it is difficult, I should be able to see the whole thing; I know I must be missing something.

--- EDIT ---

What I'm looking for is the equivalent of [this](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html):

```
curl --trace-ascii debugdump.txt http://www.example.com/
```

which seems to be available with the option CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION in libcurl, but *isn't* implemented in php. Boo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending *multipart/formdata*. cURL basically shows the HTTP header completely I guess. The "problem" is that multipart/formdata consist of multiple parts. This is beyond "first level HTTP headers" and part of the body of the "main HTTP body".

I don't know your environment, but you can debug using TCP traffic monitoring as well. For this, you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) - Wireshark can as well show dump files created by tcpdump.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. It seems to me that it should still be possible to get information about the "main HTTP body" of the request from cURL.

Answer (score 5):

I had a need to do precisely this, but I needed to test communication with a bank.

It is extremely easy to use Fiddler2, enable HTTPS traffic decryption, and have cURL use Fiddler2 as a proxy for debugging in this situation:

```
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll try that next time.

Comment: No problem, you may also want to remember to set cURL to accept ALL certs temporarily since Fiddler2 uses its own (in order to intercept HTTPS traffic and decrypt it).  I believe it's something like: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);